# Unexpected Character when Parsing .NET-Encoded JSON with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, unicode, asp.net-webpages

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Pages app, and I'm seeing a problem where the Javascript `JSON.parse()` method is unable to parse JSON output by the .NET `Json.Encode()` method.  My specific problem is with the ampersand (&) character (Unicode U+0026).

For example, executing this code:

```
object SomeObject = new { SomeProperty = "A&B" };
Response.Write(Json.Encode(SomeObject));
```

In my .cshtml file results in the following content in the response:

```
{"SomeProperty":"A\u0026B"}
```

Which leads to a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` in my JavaScript:

```
function SomeCallback(aRequest) {
    if (aRequest.status === 200) {
        var lResponseJSON = JSON.parse(aRequest.Response); // Error on this line
    }
}
```

How can I get the .NET JSON encoding and the JS JSON decoding to play nice when special characters are involved?

(Preferably, short of manually going through the stringified JSON before it's parsed to replace the unicode encodings)

EDIT: Might be worth mentioning that using `Json.Write(SomeObject, Response.Output)` instead of `Response.Write(Json.Encode(SomeObject))` has no effect on the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to be somewhat different that you are showing:

When I run this code through my console:

```
var k = JSON.parse('{"SomeProperty":"A\u0026B"}')
console.log(k);
// Object {SomeProperty: "A&B"}
```

everything behaves correctly.

Though it looks strange, this is valid JSON:

```
{"SomeProperty":"A\u0026B"}
```

Comment: Developer console shows:

    aRequest: XMLHttpRequest
    response: "{"SomeProperty":"A\u0026B"}"

As my response content.

Comment: Images for clarity:
The error: http://i.imgur.com/8ySmAxX.png
The object contents: http://i.imgur.com/NVrolxT.png